# sql pulling the latest data into another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables **Camera** with columns - [*Id, Name* ] and **CameraImages** with columns - [*CamerId(FK), DateAdded, FileLocation*]. I have a system where i have allocated a bunch of cameras and new cameraImages gets stored each day. I need to add a new Column into **Cameras** called [*LatestCameraImageLocation*] . I also need to write a sql script to loop through my existing **CameraImages**, find the latest CamerImage for each Camera and write the *FileLocation* from the CameraImage into the *LatestCameraImageLocationColumn* in **Cameras**. I have tried a bunch of methods including cte but can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: Why do you want to loop? You;re writing SQL so a loop would be horrifically slow. Also, this sounds more like a candidate for a `VIEW`, as otherwise you'll probably state later on you want to `UPDATE` your table with the new latest image (all the time).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `not exists` as follows:

```
Select c.*, ci.filelocation as latestcameraimage
  From camera c 
  Join cameraimage ci on c.id = ci.cameraid
 Where not exists
       (Select 1 from cameraimage cii 
         Where cii.camerid = ci.cameraid
           And cii.dateadded > ci.dateadded)
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what this is for it might be worth rethinking your model a bit. But strictly for the question asked

```
UPDATE Camera
  FROM (SELECT CameraID,
               FileLocation
          FROM (SELECT FileLocation,
                       CameraID,
                       ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
                         ( PARTITION BY cameraID
                               ORDER BY dateAdded DESC
                         ) rn
                  FROM CameraImages
               )
         WHERE rn = 1
       ) UPDT
   SET Camera.LatestCameraImageLocation = UPDT.fileLocation
 WHERE Camera.ID = UPDT.CameraID;
```

If it was me I'd consider creating a view though, because otherwise this update will need run whenever there is a change in CameraImage. A view approach will stay in sync without intervention.

```
 CREATE VIEW CAMERA_LOCATION AS 
    SELECT cam.id,
           ci.FileLocation
      FROM Camera cam
     INNER
      JOIN
           (SELECT FileLocation,
                   CameraID,
                   ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
                     ( PARTITION BY cameraID
                           ORDER BY dateAdded DESC
                     ) rn
              FROM CameraImages
           ) ci
        ON cam.id = ci.cameraID
       AND rn = 1;
```